# sorting arrows jtable column header

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

Does anyone know how to implement the up and down arrows of a JTable column header while sorting its rows?

I have made my own way of sorting and it is triggered by listening to mouse clicks by mouseadapter and the only things that is left is the **visibility of such arrows** on the header...

Is there also a way to easily implement a sortable jtable?

---

I finished doing all the sorting and one last thing that i can't do is show the sorting arrows..

i don't want to make a new one but i failed to find if there is an setEnableArrow or something..

any ideas about this?

Comment: ok, what i just want now is the implementation of the arrows...

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look in the source code of the [`DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/swing/table/DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer.java.html). In the `getTableCellRendererComponent` you see from where those icons are retrieved (e.g. `UIManager.getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon")`) and how this icon is set (`setIcon(sortIcon);`)

Comment: @Steve typically the source code is included if you download an official JDK. Or just a quick google and you can [use this site instead](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/swing/table/DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer.java.html)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't mess up with the `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer`. The problem with this one, is that it's just that, the default. Each LaF is supposed to create a subclass of this one and do its own rendering there. My suggestion is to use a LaF that provides this functionality out of the box. I think that TinyLaf can do this but I'm not sure. You *can* subclass `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer` but you risk alienating the header rendering from the rest of the LaF.

So how to do it? Unicode to the rescue! Refer to the [geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes) page and use what you like. I picked the `'\u25B2'` and `'\u25BC'` triangles. But then I had to hide the dreaded Swing icon:

```
UIManager.put( "Table.ascendingSortIcon", new EmptyIcon() );
UIManager.put( "Table.descendingSortIcon", new EmptyIcon() );
```

**Be very careful with the above lines!** They will replace the icons for **all** JTables in your application which *might* not be what you want. Then you should be able to see something like that:

[image: Sorting icon unicode]

Empty Icon can be like:

```
class EmptyIcon implements Icon, Serializable {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {}
    public int getIconWidth() { return width; }
    public int getIconHeight() { return height; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to implement sorting:

```
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    TableRowSorter<MyModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyModel> (model);
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
    jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you use [JXtable](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-21-2006-05-21/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html) instead of a Jtable?

these tables have the arrows in the header to sort them and they are easy to use...
worth trying...