# JTable column sorter shows two arrows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using `JTable` and for the column I am allowing multiple row selection and allowing the table to be sorted. The table has a column which is `Boolean`(check-box). When this `check-box` is unselected for all the rows and I sort the table by any of the columns then I can select the rows correctly. But when there is at least one check-box is selected and I sort the table then row selection is not working i.e. if I click on `i`-th row then some other row is getting selected. But it is also the case that when there are one or multiple check-boxes are selected but I haven't sorted the table by any of the columns the I'm able to select the rows correctly. Probably it's for the sorting mechanism. I can see `two` arrows on the column header where it should be only one. I've attached the screenshot. I think if somehow I can make the arrow single(don't know how) then I'll get the solution.

This is how I'm allowing multi selection:

```
    variantTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    variantTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

And model is like below:

```
mVariantTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object[][] {
                        {null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, false},
                    },
                    new String[] {
                        "a", "v", "c", "Zugeordnet"
                    }
                ) {
                    Class<?>[] columnTypes = new Class<?>[] {
                        String.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class
                    };
                    @Override
                    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                        return columnTypes[columnIndex];
                    }
                });
```

Screenshot below:

[image: Here's the image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting arrows jtable column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745181/sorting-arrows-jtable-column-header)

Comment: @ArifMustafa Thanks for the help but this doesn't solve the problem. I don't want to remove the icon only but the functionality of one out of the two

Comment: The problem is not with  the code you added to your question AFAICT. Can you please include a [MCVE] in your question?

Comment: @TT. which portion of code should I include as there's no custom sorting mechanism in my code.

Comment: Well, create a small, minimum program that people can copy/paste in their Java environment to see what the problem is.

Comment: Strange, but note: a column of boolean values provides no uniqueness, so sorting is ambiguous. Maybe that is involved, improbable as it seems.